# I need to send whole word at a time but Selenium webdriver send keys alphabet by alphabet.. Any suggestion

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, selenium

Here is my sample code: I am reading from SQL and for each recod I need to go to the website and enter data into the fields but it is entering one alphabet by alphabet.. like typing

```
// Declare variables
                string tempaccount = "";
                string tempcounter = "";

                tempaccount = myReader2["acctno"].ToString();
                tempcounter = myReader2["counter"].ToString();


                string recipient_last_name = myReader2["last"].ToString();
                string recipient_first_name = myReader2["first"].ToString();
                //---------------------------------------------------------------------
                //------------------------ Data Entry ---------------------------------
                //---------------------------------------------------------------------


               IWebElement tPATIENT_LAST_NAME = driver.FindElement(By.Name("LAST_NAME"));
                tPATIENT_LAST_NAME.SendKeys(recipient_last_name);

                IWebElement FIRST_NAME = driver.FindElement(By.Name("tPATIENT_FIRST_NAME"));
                tPATIENT_FIRST_NAME.SendKeys(recipient_first_name);
```

Comment: @all: If i use excel instead of SQL database, it works fine.. any idea

Comment: The code looks fine. What do you mean by, "it doesn't work"?

Comment: It send keys but very slow... like someone manually typing it..

Comment: How are you grabbing the data out of the database? Using a DataReader? If so, how long does the data take to come back. Since you said using Excel works fine, the problem is likely to be at the database side of things.

Comment: first im selecting the records and then reading one by one... and reading is pretty quick. Im sure its database but not sure hot to rectify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, if there are upper case letters then for every send key, driver sends the shift and then sends the letter.. thats why it was taking little bit of time...

Since now i made changes to my code as shown below, it send keys in fraction on seconds.

```
string recipient_last_name = myReader2["last"].ToString().ToLower();
IWebElement tPATIENT_LAST_NAME = driver.FindElement(By.Name("LAST_NAME"));  
          tPATIENT_LAST_NAME.SendKeys(recipient_last_name);
```